# How to change ux element tags in Azure AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to control the elements that are generated dynamically by the azure b2c.

Like change the element `<p>` tags to `<h2>` on email signup page,

so that "Your Details" appear inside a header tag.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the Azure AD B2C There is a way to customize the interface of user experiences for sign-up, sign-in, and profile editing. Please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-customize-ui) for more information.

We can use javascript in the B2C but for your scenario it wont work. As per the Guidelines we should change the html elements order using javascript. Please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-customize-ui) it may help you for future reference.

Comment: I have gone through this document before. I know we can change content displayed inside the "initial_intro" using the localisation and even control style as suggested in the document. But how do I change the element <p> tag to <h2>? I want to change the element tag that's been rendered inside the api tag.

Comment: sorry we can't change those elements